# can I get T**(c style 2 dimensional array ) from boost::multi_array<T, 2>?

Tags: c++, arrays, boost, multidimensional-array

because I want to use boost::multi_array<>, and at the same time, there's legacy library requires c style 2d array.

Comment: `boost::multiarray` is not a jagged array (which is what `T**` can be).

Comment: I wouldn't say that `T**` is a "C style 2 dimensional array".

Comment: I shouldn't have said 'c style 2d array', I should say just 'T**'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T **` is *not* a C-style array. Built-in C-style arrays are implemented through index recalculation technique overlaid on an ordinary 1D array.

`T **` would be a manually implemented "multi-level" 2D array. This sort of 2D array uses a two-level implementation, with first level array being an array of pointers pointing to second-level arrays containing actual data. This is a completely different approach, not compatible with built-in arrays.

Memory layout used by `boost::multi_array<T, 2>` is the same as for built-in C-style array, i.e. it is a 1D array that "pretends" to be 2D through index recalculation. You cannot "extract" a `T **`-style array from it, since the two-leveled memory structure simply does not exist in `boost::multi_array`.

This actually raises the question of what kind of array your legacy libraries require: `T **`-style array or C-style array, since these are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the boost multi array is layout in the same way as primitive c++ array wouldn't you be able to then access it in a standard way?

From [boost multi_array reference](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/multi_array/doc/reference.html#multi_array):

> c_storage_order
>
> ...
>
> c_storage_order is used to specify that an array should store its
>   elements using the same layout as that used by primitive C++
>   multidimensional arrays, that is, from last dimension to first. This
>   is the default storage order for the arrays provided by this library.

And at the bottom:

> This library is analogous to boost::array in that it augments C style
>   N-dimensional arrays, as boost::array does for C one-dimensional arrays.

Meaning it just adds the wrapper for easier declaration and access but under the hood it sounds like standard multi-dimensional array.

Have you tried? Do you see any issues?

**EDIT**

As it was pointed out before, it seems to be a 1D array. But it seems it can be accessed like this:

```
#include <boost/multi_array.hpp>

void f( int * arr )
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " start" << std::endl;
    for( int y = 0; y != 2; ++y )
    {
        for ( int x = 0; x != 4; ++x )
        {
            //  std::cout << arr[x][y] << "," ;  // compiler does not like
            std::cout << arr[ x + ( y * 4 ) ] << "," ;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " end" << std::endl;
}
```

And

```
void multi()
{
    typedef boost::multi_array< int, 2 > arr_t;
    typedef arr_t::index index;

    arr_t a( boost::extents[2][4],  boost::c_storage_order() );

    int v( 0 );

    for ( index i = 0; i != 2; ++i )
        for( index j = 0; j != 4; ++j )
        {
            a[i][j] = ++v;
        }

    v = 0;
    for ( index i = 0; i != 2; ++i )
        for( index j = 0; j != 4; ++j )
        {
            assert( a[i][j] == ++v );
        }

    for ( index i = 0; i != 2; ++i )
    {
        for( index j = 0; j != 4; ++j )
        {
            std::cout << a[i][j] << "," ;
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    f( a.data() );
}
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,
5,6,7,8,
void f(int*) start
1,2,3,4,
5,6,7,8,
void f(int*) end
```

Comment: Thanks.
I tried: 
    boost::multi_array<int, 2> arr(boost::extents[2][2]);
    int** p = reinterpret_cast<int**>(arr.data());
    p[0][0] = 12;
it crashed.